# Select element's id from php loop using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, select, loops

I have two dropdown lists containing customers info.
Using PHP for loop, I have allowed to enter 5 customers details at a time.

```
for($i=1; $i<6; $i++)
{
   echo "<tr><td><select id=\"customer_" . $i . "_class\"></select></td>";
   echo "<td><select id=\"customer_" . $i . "_age\"></select></td></tr>";
}
```

Now I want to execute a jQuery function in such a way that if, for example, customer_2_class changes, it executes some function to its corresponding customer_2_age.

```
$("#customer_?_clas").change(function()
{
   //some function to execute on corresponding customer_?_age
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class to your `<select>` and move the id to another attribute, like `data`:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><select class=\"customer_class\" data-id=\"$i\"></select></td>";
echo "<td><select class=\"customer_age\" data-id=\"$i\"></select></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

And in your javascript:

```
$('.customer_class').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  // process customer_class with this id
});
```

Comment: In addition to the `data-id` attribute, adding the `id` attribute wouldn't hurt here since the `id` selector is much faster than the regular attribute selector.

Comment: I like the use of the class attributes (the only reason I didn't suggest it in my answer is that you already had), but I'd probably do it without the `data-id` attribute, instead finding the matching age select with something like `$(this).closest('tr').find('.customer_age')`.

Comment: Thanks guys,
Now you have the data-id in var id.
How do I execute a function for customer_class with that specific data-id?
Sorry for this newbie question..

Comment: @AsadoQureshi You should create a new question with more HTML/JS code and explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('select[id$="_class"]').change(function() {
```

It might be worth browsing through the [full list of jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').
   filter(function() { 
       return /^customer_[0-9]_class$/.test(this.id); // filter on select 
                                                      // based on id format
   }) 
   . change(function() {                              // binding change 
                                                      // to filtered select
       var num = this.id.match(/\d/)[0];              // get numerical value 
                                                      // of select box on change

       $('#customer_' + num + '_age')                 // point to target select 
            .css('background', '#f00');               // do something
   });
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/94/)**